# Extract certain conditions/values inside a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have a dataset, which I developed using a loop (code below).

```
## A subset of the data
deficit = (E_daily[:,160,100] - P_daily[:,160,100])  # A view of `deficit` is given below
deficit_cum = np.zeros([365])   
start = 0
stop = 0
for i in range(365):
    deficit_cum[i] = deficit[i] + deficit_cum[i-1]
    if deficit_cum[i] >= 0:
        if np.nanmax(deficit_cum) <= deficit_cum[i]:
            stop = i
        else:
            continue
    else:
        deficit_cum[i] = 0
        if np.nanmax(deficit_cum) > deficit_cum[i]:
            continue
        else:
            start = i     #Start is not defined correctly by me
```

This is how `deficit` looks, before the loop
[image]

Now I am also interested in the index of the values from where my loop starts and where it ends. I know it's confusing, here is an example (below is how `deficit_cum` looks):

[image]

In the figure above, greenline defines `start` (x-axis) and redline defines `stop` (x-axis) from the code. So basically I want the maximum value to be my `stop` point. But I want my `start` to be less than stop and there shouldn't be any negative point between `start` and `stop`. **So for the diagram below my `start` should be around 111 and `stop` should be around 236.**

I think I know how to get `stop` (code above), but I am still having trouble defining `start`.
*[Additional information: My `start` should be the index of last zero before the global maximum and `stop` should be the index of global maximum]*

Comment: what you want? you want always `start` less than `stop`?

Comment: Are you using pandas or simply numpy?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi. Yes, I want the `start` to be the point where actually the loop starts to accumulate values (the greenline). So it should always be less than `stop`. So basically the `start` should be the first zero between greenline and redline and there should be no negative value after that zero or another zero.

Comment: @FlorianBernard. I am using numpy.

Comment: @Ep1c1aN look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a list and you want to find a `min` before a `max` named `start` and `stop`, assuming that the list named `a`, you can use `argmax` and `argmin` functions, so we have :

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,6,6,6,4,5])
start = np.argmin(a)

b = np.where(a==a.max()) # find indices in which max values exist
b = np.reshape(b,-1)
new_array = a[:b[-1]+1] # make a new array, it starts from 0 to index of last max value
# new_array = = [1,2,3,6,6,6]

c = np.where(new_array==new_array.min())
c = np.reshape(c,-1)

start = c[-1]
stop = b[-1]
```

Comment: You script doesn't work with the following array a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 4, 5]. And a list do not have a.max().

Comment: @FlorianBernard thanks for mentioning this issue, `a` should be numpy array.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi. Your code does provide the `max` or `stop`, but it is not able to tell the `start` or 'the index of zero before the global maximum'. It gives me a zero for `start`.

Comment: @Ep1c1aN i don't see your data, but if it happens, that's because `min` element before `max` is at index `0` !

Comment: and that's because my code looks for the first occurrence of `min` before the last occurrence of last `max` !

Comment: are you looking for the last occurrence of `min` before the last occurrence of `max`?

Comment: Sorry for bad communication, I don't want the first occurrence of zero. I want the last occurrence of zero, before the global maximum. See figure 2 in the question, where `start` is around 111.

Comment: @Ep1c1aN look at my answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201411/discussion-between-ep1c1an-and-mohsen-fatemi).

Answer (score 0):

OK so let's try something like this.

First we compute deficit.

```py
deficit = np.absolute(E_daily[:,160,100] - P_daily[:,160,100])
deficit_cum = np.cumsum(deficit)
```

Start index is where day > day - 1, and reverse for stop.

```py
start = np.where(np.diff(deficit) > 0)[0][0] + 1
stop = np.where(np.diff(defict[start:]) < 0)[0][0] + 2
```

Let's see it in action.

```py
deficit = np.array([1,1,2,3,6,6,6,4,5])
start = np.where(np.diff(deficit) > 0)[0][0] + 1
stop = np.where(np.diff(defict[start:]) < 0)[0][0] + 2
```

Results

```
start = 2 # deficit[2] == 2
stop = 6 # deficit[6] == 6
```

### Docs

- [np.absolute](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)
- [np.cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)
- [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
- [np.diff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

### Note

As you used numpy you should think with matrices, and forget about loop. It's a good pratice to use numpy built-in function to perform operation. Is faster, as well as reproducible.

Comment: `start` and `stop` would have been list of indices, not a single index for `start` and `stop` !

Comment: Consider this example : `>>> a = [1,2,3,6,6,6,0,4,5]` i've calculated `start` and `stop` in the way you mentioned, this is the answer `>>> start
array([1, 2, 3, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
>>> stop
array([6], dtype=int64)`

Comment: @FlorianBernard. I am not sure, if `np.cumsum(deficit)` is the way to go. My deficit_cum values reset after a value less than zero is reached and then it again starts to add up from zero. Your solution might have worked for all positive values, but not work for a dataset with multiple peaks around zero. I tried your code too for my dataset, it didn't work.